# How can i setup default paths, variables, etc when i launch the IronPython Console?

Tags: ironpython

Everytime i start up the IronPython console to do some playing, the first thing i find myself doing is sys.path.append('myscripts')

How can i have the console load default stuff such as appending paths, importing .NET stuff -- that way i dont have to type it in everytime i launch the console.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For paths, you can set the IRONPYTHONPATH environment variable; it's a semi-colon separated list of paths that are added sys.path on startup.

For imports, I like -i option: create a .py file that has your common imports, and run it with `ipy -i myscript.py` (I would recommend creating a batch file for that).

You could also modify site.py, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it will get overwritten if you upgrade your IronPython.